# Angular service wait for database connection

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm running into an asynchronous problem while setting up an angular database service using node mssql.

Essentially I want this service to the be the central location for querying from the database.

The issue I'm facing is that when the app loads I need it to do an initial query, and when this happens the connection method has not yet finished.

How can I make the query function wait for pool to resolve to a value before executing?

```
const sql = require('mssql');

userManagerApp.service('SqlService', function() {
    var pool;

    var connect = async function() {
        pool = await sql.connect('mssql://user:pass@host/database')
    }
    connect();


    var query = async function (query) {
        try {
            var results = await pool.request().query(query).recordset;
            return results;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    var theService = {
        query : query
    };
    return theService;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the example on [NPM MSSQL](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)
Try this approach:

```
const sql = require('mssql');

userManagerApp.service('SqlService', function() {

    var query = async function (query) {
        try {
            let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig)
            let result = await pool.request().query(query).recordset
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

    var theService = {
        query : query
    };
    return theService;
});
```

Comment: The problem with is that the connection will need to be terminated after each query. I'm hoping to have a persistent connection.

Comment: Actually I can just set a global variable for the connection and treat it like a singleton. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`service` service is being misused because there's already `this` service instance, no need to return a new one.

A promise of connection should be stored and chained in all methods that depend on it, this is a common recipe (used in Mongoose, for instance):

```
userManagerApp.service('SqlService', function() {
    this.poolPromise = sql.connect('mssql://user:pass@host/database');
    this.query = async (query) => {
        try {
            const pool = await this.poolPromise;
            const results = await pool.request().query(query).recordset;
            return results;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
});
```